# Where the heck do I put a period in these sentences?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, parentheses, periods

Hullo all,
I've been given a doozy of a job that is thick with sentences like this:

Student will demonstrate emphasizing with the feelings of another by remembering a similar past experience and sharing it for comfort (e.g., “Last year I was unfairly accused of cheating by a teacher so I know how you must feel now”)

and:

Student will make a reliable decision in play (e.g., when given choices of what to do next with the doll, student can choose the next step. “Does she want to go swimming or eat broccoli?”)

and also:

Student will express more complex emotions using visual supports, communication and affect (e.g., sick, tired, anxiety, confusion, etc)

Where does one put a period in these?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What are you forgetting to end your sentences with periods for? Otherwise it would be just like if you

Comment: Did you mean "empathizing"?

Comment: @Hot Licks - Thanks for that catch. There's a lot of that in this job, but that's a whole other ball of wax.

Comment: @KannE - There are a LOT of sentence structure changes I could make, but I doubt my client would pay for the many extra hours that would take me ;-) They just want minor stuff fixed.

Comment: If you meant "empathizing" you should edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: In my opinion you could end each statement of the action the student should take with a full stop (I'm British, a period is a length of time or an occurrence of menstruation to me) and then present the examples in a separate sentence. However that's a style choice, not a grammatical one.

Comment: Rule 1: You touched, you own it, and all mistakes you leave behind. You will be blamed for them anyway. Rule 2: You can start a list with 'e.g.,' OR end a list with 'etc.', but not both. (Take out the etc, which should be etc. always.)

Comment: Whoever wrote that first sentence and the others should be fired for incompetence. I mean, this is another perfect example of a naked emperor....."Student will demonstrate emphasizing with the feelings of another by remembering a similar past experience." They mean: Students will demonstrate they understand the meaning of empathizing with the feelings of others by x. For example.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I will use **FULL_STOP** instead of '.'. Also, I will not correct other grammatical mistakes, such as missing articles (e.g. it should be ***the** student can choose the next step*). I will try to limit myself to correcting the punctuation (except that I have used *empathizing*, which is a perfectly fine word; in contrast, ***emphasizing** with the feelings of another*, as you have it now, is not acceptable.)

I will show one way to place the periods so that you have complete sentences, which is at least consistent with *The Chicago Manual of Style*. Of course, you should actually use whatever style manual suits the needs of your client.

I know you said you don't want to make 'major' changes to the text. Nevertheless, unless these are supposed to be mere sketches or bullet-pouints in a presentation (in which case, do you really want or need the periods?), I urge you to do a bit of rewriting on these sentences. If they are supposed to be part of a self-contained, in-principle-publishable academic text, they **need** to be rewritten!

In the end, the periods just go to the end. Only in the second sentence is another intervention needed, namely, replacing a period in the middle by a colon.

> Student will demonstrate empathizing with the feelings of another by remembering a similar past experience and sharing it for comfort (e.g., “Last year I was unfairly accused of cheating by a teacher so I know how you must feel now”)**FULL_STOP**

> Student will make a reliable decision in play (e.g., when given choices of what to do next with the doll, student can choose the next step: “Does she want to go swimming or eat broccoli?”)**FULL_STOP**

(Note that there is now a colon rather than a period after *next step*.)

> Student will express more complex emotions using visual supports, communication and affect (e.g., sick, tired, anxiety, confusion, etc.)**FULL_STOP**

Note that I have placed a period after *etc*. I did this because *e.g.* had periods; either both of those should have periods, or neither. (Thanks to Edwin Ashworth for pointing this out.)

Comment: Interesting that eg is displayed as e.g. but etc as etc, isn't it? But your suggestions are not the only ways recommended to use tricky terminal punctuation. You suggest doubly punctuating << ... broccoli?). >> but not << ... confusion, etc). >>. Have you a source endorsing such choices? // All this has been covered before on ELU, with the bottom line '_Check which style guide you're supposed to be using at the moment._'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I fixed the inconsistent punctuation of *etc.* —thanks! I do make the disclaimer that this isn't the only way to go. My idea was to change as little as possible in the original, because that is what the OP indicated she wants. As for sourcing, I felt these choices, while not the only ones possible, are noncontroversial enough. Do you really think that there is some doubt about whether any reputable source would recommend the double punctuation in the *broccoli* sentence? But, yes: *The Chicago Manual of Style,* for one, would seem to be OK with it. I've added that as a comment.

Comment: Hey, it wasn't your inconsistency. It was interesting that the period didn't occur where it would  have been messy (end-of-sentence _etc_.). // I doubly punctuate where I think it clarifies and/or want to make a point. I once found a reference condoning this. Of course, it's great not to have editors / profs / teachers with red pens at the ready. // Here, 'Student will' already shows headlinese, so really strict punctuation rules would seem rather usurious.